# iOS Development with sybase unwired platform

Tags: xcode4, sup

I have created Application using MIM Chart library but now i need to migrate that application to SUP how and where to start? how to Configure SUP in Xcode? After Configure can i migrate native xcode app to SUP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [SUP documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/)

Select your SUP version and the project type (object api, OData, etc)